# jQuery show icon with toggle event

Tags: javascript, html, slidetoggle, jquery

I have create custom `toogle script` to `show/hide` content.

Currently when you click first and then second text, icon mechanism working perfect. but when you click first text and again click first icon mechanism not working.

**My JS Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.togglelink').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = $(this).next('.toggle');

        $('.toggle').not(elem).hide('fast');
        elem.slideToggle('fast');

        if (elem.is(':visible')) {
            var openslide = $(this).attr("id");

            if (openslide == 'slideNavToggle') {
                $("#where-slide-down").hide();
                $("#where-slide-up").show();

                $("#inspiration-slide-down").show();
                $("#inspiration-slide-up").hide();
                $("#need-slide-down").show();
                $("#need-slide-up").hide();
            }

            if (openslide == 'slideInspToggle') {
                $("#inspiration-slide-down").hide();
                $("#inspiration-slide-up").show();

                $("#where-slide-down").show();
                $("#where-slide-up").hide();
                $("#need-slide-down").show();
                $("#need-slide-up").hide();
            }

            if (openslide == 'slideToggle') {
                $("#need-slide-down").hide();
                $("#need-slide-up").show();

                $("#where-slide-down").show();
                $("#where-slide-up").hide();
                $("#inspiration-slide-down").show();
                $("#inspiration-slide-up").hide();
            }

        }
    });
    $('.toggle').hide('fast');
});
```

My Fiddle: [Sample](http://goo.gl/sm4Ybo)

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the icon is not restored?

Comment: yes click to `Choose your next destination` and again click you will find that icons direction is not working. :( I don't know how to do that operation.

Comment: You currently swap icons only `if (elem.is(":visible"))`, and reverse situation is don't even handled.

Comment: You mean i need to check in else condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:
 You just have to change from show/hide to toggle. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MnyJr/)

```
$('.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var elem = $(this).next('.toggle');

$('.toggle').not(elem).hide('fast');
elem.slideToggle('fast');

if (elem.is(':visible')) {
    var openslide = $(this).attr("id");

    if (openslide == 'slideNavToggle') {
        $("#where-slide-down").toggle();
        $("#where-slide-up").toggle();

        $("#inspiration-slide-down").show();
        $("#inspiration-slide-up").hide();
        $("#need-slide-down").show();
        $("#need-slide-up").hide();
    }

    if (openslide == 'slideInspToggle') {
        $("#inspiration-slide-down").toggle();
        $("#inspiration-slide-up").toggle();

        $("#where-slide-down").show();
        $("#where-slide-up").hide();
        $("#need-slide-down").show();
        $("#need-slide-up").hide();
    }

    if (openslide == 'slideToggle') {
        $("#need-slide-down").toggle();
        $("#need-slide-up").toggle();

        $("#where-slide-down").show();
        $("#where-slide-up").hide();
        $("#inspiration-slide-down").show();
        $("#inspiration-slide-up").hide();
    }

}
});

$('.toggle').hide('fast');
```